# iBeacon to detect accessory proximity (whilst app in background)

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, battery

I would like to use [iBeacon](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/) to detect the proximity to a hardware (emitting iBeacon signals) when the app runs in background.

- Is there a way to get **CLLocationManager** to detect the location/proximity to an iBeacon whilst the app is running in background?
- Does using iBeacon affect the iOS battery performance in a variable way  depending on the **transmission frequency** of the iBeacon hardware? In other words, if we have an iBeacon that has a high **transmission frequency** will the iOS device drain more **battery** as it will be receiving more signal than when using an iBeacon with a lower transmission frequency?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it's possible to force ranging (estimating proximity) in the background on iOS. The problem is, that it has big impact on battery and potential user privacy implications, so it's unlikely that Apple would accept such an app into the App Store.

The proper (as in recommended by Apple) way for an app to interact with beacons in the background, is with region monitoring: simply detecting whether the user is in range of a beacon. If you want to force background ranging though, there's a short guide for that: https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/203914068-Is-it-possible-to-use-beacon-ranging-in-the-background-

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways to use iBeacons - checking for region changes, or checking proximity to beacons.

In the background, you can't poll a beacon for proximity directly, you must instead use `startMonitoringForRegion:` to monitor for the crossing of the region boundary. Once that boundary is detected, your app will wake up to process in the background and handle what you want it to handle.

The `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` dictionary contains a key that indicates your app was launched due to a location event.

The transmission frequency of the beacon only affects the battery life of the beacon.

Comment: Thanks. Does this work also when the app is in background?

Comment: Region monitoring does. Beacon proximity doesn't.

What you could do is set up region monitoring to wake up your app to the background, and once running you can start checking beacon proximity.